# Admin access with flutter - hide and show widget and button based on User right firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am working to build an admin access to a client. Among the visibility I need to constraint is the visibility of the button.

When changing access to user to admin, the button is not appearing back. The dependent boolean condition is mentioned below.

```
  bool _show = false;

  void showFloationButton() {

    setState(() {
      _show = true;
    });
  }

  void hideFloationButton() {
    setState(() {
      _show = false;
    });
  }
    void userAdminAccess() async {
      FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        if ( currentUser != null) {
          Firestore.instance
            .collection('Users')
        .where('isAdmin', isEqualTo: true);
  } return showFloationButton();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it wants to perform a query, but it is not actually doing so.  It's just building a Query object.  You have to use `get()` to actually make that query happen, and await the response:

```
var querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection('Users')
    .where('isAdmin', isEqualTo: true)
    .get();
if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
    // there is at least one document returned by this query
}
else {
    // there are not matching documents
}
```

I suggest learning more about how to perform queries in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#document--query-snapshots).

Note that what you're doing is potentially very expensive.  It seems to me that you should probably get a single document for the user, identified by their UID, and look for a field within that document.  Getting all admins could incur a lot of reads unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks Doug, get is return in error, but more broadly, your comment on the UID and using a specific field, do you know a specific best practice?

Comment: Use the user's UID as the ID of a document for each user.